# Repeater with 2 datasources

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I got 2 database-tables, `USER and MESSAGE`

```
USER: UserID, FirstName, LastName 
MESSAGE: MessageID, UserID, Content
```

I am using a repeater to show the messages and it retrieves the data from the MESSAGE-table which contains a UserID which is also shown. I want to show the firstname and lastname instead of the UserID, but how I can do this in a repeater? Do I need to use 2 datasources?

The MESSAGE-Table doesn't contain FirstName and LastName, so I am reading the FirstName and LastName from the USER-table based on the UserID in the MESSAGE-table.

```
private List<Message> listMessages = Database.GetMessages();
repeaterMessages.DataSource = listMessages;
repeaterMessages.DataBind();
```

With this code above I can show the MessageID, UserID, and Content in a repeater, but not he FirstName and LastName.

I really don't have any clue what I can do...

I want to have something like this (inside the repeater):

```
MessageID: 1
Mike Johnson
This is the content.
```

But what I got is:

```
MessageID: 1
UserID: 43
This is the content.
```

Comment: As your Message is linked with the User, so keep a object of User in the Message Entity and not only the UserId.

Comment: @AbhishekJain You mean I should also add two extra entities to the Message-table? (FirstName and LastName)?

Comment: As you are having a Entity for Message, you must also be having a Entity for User. so Your Message Entity will contain MessageID, User(User Whole Entity), Content and User entity will contain UserId, FirstName, LastName, UserName, password etc. So while retrieving Messages from the database also retrieve the User Details with each message.

Answer (score 0):

The message class has `MessageID`, `UserID` and `Content` as members. You need to select the `Message` joined with the `User` and project only the columns which you want to display.

For instance you can define a class named `DisplayableMessage`, for instance which will have members, such as `MessageID`, `UserName` and `Content`. You can define a method for the class, let's name it `GetDisplayableMessage` which will initialize a List of DisplayableMessage based on `Message` and `User` data. And then you can associate this method to the `DataSource` of the `Repeater`.